# Applescript: "set user interaction level to never interact" not working in illustrator

Tags: plugins, applescript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to set it so that there's no user interaction when I open up my illustrator file using applescript, but the standard:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
activate
set user interaction level to never interact
open theFile without dialogs
```

doesn't work for this plugin I have installed that checks for white overprints.
If it were up to me I'd just uninstall the plugin but it's for a work pc.

I also tried clicking the button automatically (with help from Tim Joe) by using:

```
try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            click button "OK" of window "Adobe Illustrator"
        end tell
    end tell
end try
```

and I've tried

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Adobe Illustrator"
    keystroke return 
  end tell
end tell
```

Does anyone know a way of solving this?

below is the full code as it currently stands:

```
set saveLocation to ((path to desktop) as string) --place to save the files
set theFile to choose file with prompt "Choose the Illustrator file to get outlines on"
set outputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the output folder"
tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of theFile
set fullPath to (saveLocation & fileName) --file path of new .ai
set fileName to (text 1 thru ((length of fileName) - 3) of fileName) --remove .ai from fileName
set olPath to text 1 thru ((length of fullPath) - 3) of fullPath & "_OL.ai" --path of outlined file


 tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
activate
ignoring application responses
    open theFile without dialogs
end ignoring
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Illustrator"
        repeat 60 times -- wait up to 60 seconds for WOPD window to appear
            try
                tell window "White Overprint Detector"
                    keystroke return
                    exit repeat
                end tell
            on error
                delay 1
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
save current document in file fullPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save file to desktop
convert to paths (every text frame of current document) --convert text to paths
save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save another copy to desktop with name + _OL.ai 

 end tell
 tell application "Finder"
set newFolder to make new folder at saveLocation with properties {name:fileName}
move fullPath to newFolder --create new folder and move both new files into it
move olPath to newFolder
set newFolderPath to (newFolder) as string
set newFolderPath to text 1 thru -2 of newFolderPath --remove the trailing ":" 

tell current application --zip up the new folder
    set qpp to quoted form of POSIX path of newFolderPath
    do shell script "cd $(dirname " & qpp & ")
zip -r  \"$(basename " & qpp & ").zip\" \"$(basename " & qpp & ")\""
end tell
set zipFile to newFolderPath & ".zip"
move zipFile to outputFolder --move .zip to output
delete newFolder --delete folder on desktop left from zipping
 end tell


 --prepare a notification email 
 set presetText to "Hello,    


 Files Uploaded: 


  " & fileName & ".zip


 To access our FTP Server: 
 http://217.207.130.162:8080/WebInterface/login.html   

 To access our FTP server, log onto our website below: 

 Username: 
 Password: 

 Thanks, 
  Joe"
tell application "Mail" --open up prepared email
activate
set theMEssage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true,       subject:fileName, content:presetText}
  end tell
  --open file containing usernames and passwords for the FTP
  do shell script "open /Users/produser/Desktop/FTP_Users"
```

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: I think it's called: white OP detector, apparently it's made by worker72a.com, whatever that means :/

Answer (score 2):

I tracked down and installed White Overprint Detector I could see what you mean. I had to use an older version as I only have CS3, and I saw the dialog it produces when you open a document. The following worked for me to get it to dismiss:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Illustrator"
        repeat 60 times -- wait up to 60 seconds for WOPD window to appear
            try
                tell window "White Overprint Detector"
                    keystroke return
                    exit repeat
                end tell
            on error
                delay 1
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. Whereabouts in your code did you open theFile? I tried setting it before "tell system events" and after the end tell for system events but neither worked.

Comment: I'll take a look later. In the meantime, can you try wrapping your file open command between `ignoring application responses` and `end ignoring` and report what you get?

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't stop the white overprint pop-up but it does break a later part of my code. Iv put the full code up now.

Comment: @man-qa thanks. Any way you can also provide me with a copy of the file, so I can see exactly what you're working with? You can email me at ivan@ivanx.com.

Answer (score 1):

Since my original post seemed too objective to understand I will revise.

With in the tell block for illustrator look for your line that opens the file. Some commands allow with and without properties. Try applying the "without dialogs" property to look something like this.

```
    tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
        open file (VariableOfFilePath) without dialogs
    end tell
```

Update:

Two work arounds I can think of. 1) Try telling system events to tell AI to open without dialogs

```
tell application "system events"
    tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
        open file (VariableOfFilePath) without dialogs
    end tell
end tell
```

Other is just add in a bit that will just okay the prompt.

```
     try
        tell application "System Events"
           tell process "Finder"
              click button "Continue" of window "Adobe Illustrator"
           end tell
        end tell
     end try
```

Can try just having it accept the default button.

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "Finder"
      keystroke return
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The issue is he is getting prompts when he opens a file, I am suggesting to included a "without dialogs" postfix. To vote down rather then to suggest further clarification isn't any more benefiting.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim Joe, but I already had that in my code, just not in the snippet I posted, I've edited the question to show how I put it.

Comment: Thanks again but the button click didn't work either, I changed the "continue" to "OK" as that what the button says, do you think it could be because the window is called something different? P.s I've updated my code

Comment: hmm... what are the buttons options and which is selected by default

Comment: The only button is an OK button that is selected by default

Comment: try adding a line to just click the button if you can't prevent it. tell application "System Events"¬
   tell process "Finder"¬
    keystroke return¬
   end tell¬
  end tell

Comment: I tried that one too and still nothing. It didn't come up with an error message it just didn't do anything. I just had a thought, maybe its because of the "open file" command, maybe its only registering that as complete after the ok button has been hit.

Comment: In my last comment try changing "finder" to "adobe illustrator"